# Export material-UI DataGrid in excel file by making separate Export button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

So,this is my code I have to export dataGrid details making button and pass onClick function to it.We can use datagrid Toolbar component but I don't want to use it.How to export datagrid rows and columns details.

```
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", flex: 1 },
  { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", flex: 1 },
  { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", flex: 1 },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    flex: 1
  },
  {
    field: "fullName",
    headerName: "Full name",
    description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
    sortable: false,
    flex: 1,
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${
        params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
      }`
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to install xlsx by using npm-i-xlsx.After that make a button and pass onCLick function like this:

```
  <button onClick={gg}>EXPORT DATA</button>
  function gg() {
  const wb = utils.book_new();
  utils.book_append_sheet(wb, utils.json_to_sheet(rows));
  writeFileXLSX(wb, "testyy.xlsx");
}
```

or you can find my solution https://codesandbox.io/s/export-datagrid-in-excel-using-button-b34ijd?file=/src/App.js